# Error while trying to edit projects in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have installed the Android studio in my laptop which runs on windows 7 Enterprise SP1. The system type is 32-bit OS.

In the Env. Variables, I have already added JAVA_HOME as a variable and value as C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_73

I hope **the / is ok** and does not need to be \'.

When I try to open an existing project, I get a message as follows ->

***Cannot load project: com.interllij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException; Fatal Error initializing 'com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonListeners'***

I have googled the above, but all the help is for issues in OS X and not in windows.

Can some experts guide me on what I'am doing wrong.

Thanks

KR

Comment: I have now re installed the Android studio and the above error has vanished. However, I'am not able to start my AVD. i,e when I try to Launch the AVD in emulator, Nothing happens. I have Created 2 AVDs Nexus 5 API 23 x86 and Nexus 6 API 23. Please help. Thanks / KR

Answer (score 0):

I have googled it. I resolved this by installing the latest HAXM driver, changing the memory of the HAXM driver to 1024 MB and changing the memory of the AVD RAM to 512 MB.